# Continously read from log with Python to display in GTK window

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, arch

I'm trying to write a small application GUI (GTK) application with Python 3.9 and PyGObject that reads from a log file and displays the data in a GUI window.

In this particular case I'm trying to continuously read from the [systemd Journal](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/Journal), which can be done e.g. with `journalctl -f` via the terminal.

For a CLI app I saw one could use something like this to pipe the output of the log file to the STOUT of the python script:

```
p = Popen(["journalctl", "--user-unit=appToMonitor"], stdout=PIPE)
with p.stdout:
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
         print(line, end=''),
p.wait()
```

OFC for a GUI app I need to somehow hook into the GTK main loop so the above solution does not work. I did some googling and from what I can see a solution is to use `gobject.timeout_add()` to regularly poll the log file for changes.

Is this the best way to get data from a system log file or is there another solution that can be used to avoid polling? If `gobject.timeout_add()` is the way to go, how can I ensure that I'll be only adding the log lines that have been added since the last read from the log file?

Comment: There's also [`Gio.Subprocess`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gio-2.0/classes/Subprocess.html) which will integrate better with glib event loops.

Comment: Weirdly doesn't seem to be working for me though, (the internal pid variable seems to keep getting set/defaulted to 0, e.g. try calling `get_status()` on it). I'm on Python 3.9 and using the standard arch packages. But [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fthiery/da43365ceeefff8a9e3d0dd83ec24af9) that reads using a `Gio.DataInputStream` seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to use `gobject.timeout_add()`; you can just use the `threading` module, which specializes in threads, and is simpler than trying to use GTK.

#### Using `threading` to call a function

The nice thing about using `threading` is that, even though it's not part of the Gtk group of modules, it still doesn't block Gtk's main loop. Here is a simple example of a simple timeout thread using `threading`:

```py
import threading

def function():
    print("Hello!")

# Create a timer
timer = threading.Timer(
    1, # Interval (in seconds; can be a float) after which to call the function
    function # Function to call after time interval
)
timer.start() # Start the timer
```

This calls `function()` once after a period of 1 second, and then exits.

However, in your case, you want to call the function multiple times, to repeatedly check the state of the logs. For this, you can recreate the timer inside `function()`, and run it again:

```py
import threading

def function():
    global timer
    print("Hello!")

    # Recreate and start the timer
    timer = threading.Timer(1, function)
    timer.start()

timer = threading.Timer(1, function)
timer.start()
```

Now to check if any new lines have been added to the log, the program needs to read the log and then compare the lines of the most recent reading to the lines of the previous reading.

---

#### Reading the lines, and using `difflib` to compare them

First of all, to compare the lines at all, they need to be stored in two lists: one containing the most recently read set of lines, the other containing the previous set of lines. Here is an example of code that reads the output of the log, stores the lines in a list, and then prints the list:

```py
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

# The list storing the lines of the log
current_lines = []

# Read the log
p = Popen(["journalctl", "--user-unit=appToMonitor"], stdout=PIPE)
with p.stdout:
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        current_lines.append(line.decode("utf-8")) # Add the lines of the log to the list
p.wait()

print(current_lines)
```

Note that `line.decode("uft-8")` must be used, because the output of `p.stdout.readline` is in bytes. Use whatever encoding your program uses; `utf-8` is just a common encoding.

You can then use the `difflib` module to compare the two lists. Here is an example program that compares two lists of lines, and prints whatever lines are in the second list and not in the first:

```py
import difflib

# Two lists to compare
last_lines = ["Here is the first line\n"]
current_lines = ["Here is the first line\n", "and here is the second line"]

# Iterate through all the lines, and check for new ones
for line in difflib.ndiff(last_lines, current_lines):

    # Print the line only if it was not in last_lines
    if line[0] == "+": # difflib inserts a "+" for every addition
        print("Line added:", line.replace("+ ", "")) # Remove the "+" from the line and print it
```

---

#### Great, but can how do we put all this into one program?

The finale: putting all these concepts into one program that reads the output from the log every second, and adds any new lines to the text widget in the window. Here is a simple Gtk application that does just that:

```py
import difflib
import gi
import threading

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

class App(Gtk.Window):
    """The application window."""

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect("delete-event", self.quit)

        # The list of lines read from the log file
        self.current_lines = []

        # The list of previously read lines to compare to the current one
        self.last_lines = []

        # The box to hold the widgets in the window
        self.box = Gtk.VBox()
        self.add(self.box)

        # The text widget to output the log file to
        self.text = Gtk.TextView()
        self.text.set_editable(False)
        self.box.pack_start(self.text, True, True, 0)

        # A button to demonstrate non-blocking
        self.button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Click")
        self.box.pack_end(self.button, True, True, 0)

        # Add a timer thread
        self.timer = threading.Timer(0.1, self.read_log)
        self.timer.start()

        self.show_all()

    def quit(self, *args):
        """Quit."""
        # Stop the timer, in case it is still waiting when the window is closed
        self.timer.cancel()
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def read_log(self):
        """Read the log."""

        # Read the log
        self.current_lines = []
        p = Popen(["journalctl", "--user-unit=appToMonitor"], stdout=PIPE)
        with p.stdout:
            for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
                self.current_lines.append(line.decode("utf-8"))
        p.wait()

        # Compare the log with the previous reading
        for d in difflib.ndiff(self.last_lines, self.current_lines):

            # Check if this is a new line, and if so, add it to the TextView
            if d[0] == "+":
                self.text.set_editable(True)
                self.text.get_buffer().insert_at_cursor(d.replace("+ ", ""))
                self.text.set_editable(False)

        self.last_lines = self.current_lines

        # Reset the timer
        self.timer = threading.Timer(1, self.read_log)
        self.timer.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    Gtk.main()
```

The button demonstrates that `threading` doesn't block execution while waiting; you can click it all you want, even while the program is reading the log!